# Error Installing App on ipod/iphone

Tags: iphone, xcode

I am a registered iPhone developer and I am getting the following error:

> Your mobile device has encountered an
>   unexpected error (0xE8000001)  Try
>   disconnecting and powering off the
>   device; then power the device on and
>   reconnect it.

My System Specifications:

- PowerPC G5
- Mac OSx - 10.5.6
- iPhone os - 2.2.1

I am getting this error whenever I click 'Build&Go' from XCode, which I am trying to install on my iPodTouch.
I gave a proper AppId as in `info.plist(Bundle identifier)`, which is the same as configured in the iPhone program portal.

In XCode -> organizer -> Console the following error is getting displayed:

> <Error>: user mobile has uid 501
>   <Error>: mode is 0x41e8.

Answer (score 2):

I've seen a similar issue before. Have you tried disconnecting your iPhone, powering it off, powering it back on, and reconnecting?

It has worked for me, but you literally need to power it down, not just put it into standby. Hold the top "standby" button down until the "Slide to Power Off" slider appears. Slide it. Now the phone is really off.

One curious note: are you really compiling on a G5? I thought for some reason that an intel mac was required to develop iPhone apps. Perhaps that is just to get the simulator working.

Comment: An Intel Mac is what Apple officially requires, however you can install the SDK onto a PPC machine with some work.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some links to potential solutions that I ran across yesterday:

[Topic : Can't get developmental App to deploy to my iPhone (0xE800003A variation)](http://discussions.apple.com/thread.jspa?threadID=1721273)

[PreflightingApplication errors (0xE8000001) and others](http://www.talentgrouplabs.com/blog/archive/2008/08/21/preflightingapplication-errors-0xe8000001-and-others.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

If restarting your iPhone many times doesn't help, consider reinstallng the whole iPhone SDK. It worked for me once.